# Update next row columns with current row in the cursor loop

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table with records sorted by group, need to update COL2, COL3, COL4 of 2nd row with 1st row values if they are NULL. Also 3rd row with 2nd row etc. 
I am trying with CURSOR loop. How do I get next row in the CURSOR loop?

Current table

```
col1 col2  col3  col4  col5  rowNum  maxTotalInGroup
10   NULL   2     4    3      1       3
20    2    NULL  NULL  NULL   2       3                
30   NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL   3       3

40    5     9     9     3     1       2
42    NULL  3    NULL  NULL   2       2
```

Expected result

```
col1 col2  col3  col4  col5  rowNum  maxTotalInGroup
10   NULL   2     4     3       1       3
20    2     2     4     3       2       3
30    2     2     4     3       3       3

40    5    9      9     3      1       2
42    5    3      9     3      2       2
```

Comment: `LAG()` would work better for you.

Comment: Wow cursor.....

Answer (score 0):

If you accept the way of UPDATING columns one by one, you can use this following option. You will need to change column  names in 4 place in the script as indicate below.

> Please keep in mind that Update operation is a risky one. So please try with your test data first.

**Note:** Yes, Cursor is another option as @Eric said.

```
UPDATE A
SET col3 =  --CHANGE COLUMN NAME HERE
(
    SELECT col3 --CHANGE COLUMN NAME HERE
    FROM @your_table C 
    WHERE C.maxTotalInGroup = A.maxTotalInGroup 
    AND C.rowNum = (
        SELECT MAX(B.rowNum) 
        FROM @your_table B 
        WHERE B.maxTotalInGroup = A.maxTotalInGroup 
        AND B.rowNum < A.rowNum
        AND B.col3 IS NOT NULL --CHANGE COLUMN NAME HERE
    )
)
FROM @your_table A
WHERE col3 IS NULL; --CHANGE COLUMN NAME HERE
```

You can check the [DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6db958af0f3ea18e87c1bed2799fae23)